# Capybara issue: @request must be an ActionDispatch::Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, shoulda, testunit

I'm having problems making Capybara work with Rails. Just testing that suposedly interesting test thing. OK, in the attached code there are a couple of equivalent tests. The first one is made with shoulda-context + Test::Unit that comes with Rails.  The second test is made with capybara and shoulda-context too.

```
require 'integration_test_helper'

class UsersTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :all

  context "signup" do

    context "failure" do

      setup do
      @attr = { :name => "", :email => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => "" }
      end

      should "not make a new user" do
        assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
          post_via_redirect "users", :user =>@attr  # enviem les dades d'un nou usuari via create (POST /users)
          assert_template 'users/new'     # ens retorna a users/new, que significa que no s'ha creat l'usuari
          assert_select "div#error_explanation" # comprovem que conte missatges d'error
        end
      end

      should "not make a new user (capybara)" do
        assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
          visit '/signup'
          fill_in 'Name', :with => @attr[:name]
          fill_in 'Email', :with => @attr[:email]
          fill_in 'Password', :with => @attr[:password]
          fill_in 'Confirmation', :with => @attr[:password_confirmation]
          click_button 'Sign Up!'
          assert_template 'users/new'     # ens retorna a users/new, que significa que no s'ha creat l'usuari
          assert_select "div#error_explanation" # comprovem que conte missatges d'error
        end
      end
    end
end
```

While the first one works OK, the capybara one throws this error message:

```
================================================================================
Error:
test: signup failure should not make a new user (capybara). (UsersTest):
ArgumentError: @request must be an ActionDispatch::Request
    test/integration/users_test.rb:30:in `block (4 levels) in <class:UsersTest>'
    test/integration/users_test.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <class:UsersTest>'
================================================================================
```

the required *integration_test_helper.rb* file is an accumulator of all suposed solutions I've found googling around and that don't work for me.

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'

# Transactional fixtures do not work with Selenium tests, because Capybara
# uses a separate server thread, which the transactions would be hidden
# from. We hence use DatabaseCleaner to truncate our test database.
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL

  # Stop ActiveRecord from wrapping tests in transactions
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
    Capybara.reset_sessions!    # Forget the (simulated) browser state
    Capybara.use_default_driver # Revert Capybara.current_driver to Capybara.default_driver
  end
end
```

Has anybody a solution? Should I try another Integration frmawork such as webrat?

My setup is:

```
marcel@pua:~/Desenvolupament/Rails3Examples/ror_tutorial$ rake about
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.9.2 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version          1.8.15
Rack version              1.3
Rails version             3.1.3
JavaScript Runtime        therubyracer (V8)
Active Record version     3.1.3
Action Pack version       3.1.3
Active Resource version   3.1.3
Action Mailer version     3.1.3
Active Support version    3.1.3
Middleware                ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x00000002b9bac0>, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
Application root          /mnt/dropbox/Dropbox/DESENVOLUPAMENT/Rails3Examples/ror_tutorial
Environment               development
Database adapter          sqlite3
Database schema version   20120127011330
```

Also

```
shoulda-context (1.0.0)
capybara (1.1.2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're mixing up your test types and attempting to assert a template in the wrong type of test.  You should only be asserting templates within your Functional tests, where you're just directly testing a controller and not actually simulating a user interaction.

Capybara is meant specifically for Integration testing, which is essentially running tests from the viewpoint of an end-user interacting with a browser.  In these tests, you should not be asserting templates because an end-user can't see that deep into your application.  What you should instead be testing is that an action lands you on the correct path.

```
current_path.should == new_user_path
page.should have_selector('div#error_explanation')
```

See "The DSL" section in Capybara's README on git: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Official explanation for your issue: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/240

Comment: I tried to fix it following your indications, but `current_path.should == new_user_path` doesn't work. I think it is RSpec and I'm not using RSpec. Also, `assert current_path, '\signup'` doesn't work. How could I check current_path?

Comment: Actually, yeah, the *.should* matcher is part of RSpec.  My mistake.  However, `current_path` is supposed to be defined as part of the DSL that's included with `include Capybara::DSL`.  When you try to use `current_path`, are you getting a method not defined error, or something else?

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but can you explain why rspec specifically mentions the `render_template` and `redirect_to` methods for request specs, [at this relish page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec)? They aren't working for me (receiving the same error as OP) and I'm curious why.

Comment: I wish I knew.  Although I don't believe request specs should need to check which template was rendered, I also don't know why they can't based on the Rspec docs.  All I know is that assert_template (which render_template delegates to) only seems to work in controller specs.  I've always been fine with that, because it's in my controller specs that I do the template checking.

Answer (score 1):

For my completeness, because i'll know that I'll come back to this link over and over:

Those using test unit and capybara this is a good primer too: [from techiferous](http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/).

Notice the use of `assert page.has_content?("something")`

This is good to use as well as `assert_equal some_path, current_path` for testing routes.

Is it the most complete, don't know, but you don't need much more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your tips @Ryan. I was trying to figure out how to translate some RSpec Integration test examples from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec:rspec_integration_tests into Test::Unit + Capybara. The original RSpec Integration test was

```
it "should not make a new user" do
  lambda do
      visit signup_path
      fill_in "Name",         :with => ""
      fill_in "Email",        :with => ""
      fill_in "Password",     :with => ""
      fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
      click_button
      response.should render_template('users/new')
      response.should have_selector("div#error_explanation")
    end.should_not change(User, :count)
  end
end
```

So, after your answer, I supose that the original example should not contain  `response.should render_template('users/new')`

Comment: Under certain conditions, it is definitely *possible* to perform a check that a specific template was rendered within an Integration test.  I'm just of the opinion that doing so is unwise.