# Best way to test creating new project in project manager app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, integration-testing

In my app I am testing creating a new project. Currently I do it with integration test using rspec. Here's my code:

```
  3 describe "Projects" do
  4   describe "create project" do
  5     it "should create a new project" do
  6       lambda do
  7         visit root_path
  8         click_link 'new project'        
  9         fill_in :name, :with => 'Project name'
 10         fill_in :description, :with => 'This is a description'
 11         click_button 'Create'
 12       end.should change(Project, :count).by(1)
 13     end
 14   end
 15 end
```

I would also like to add after line 11 something like :

```
response.should render_template 'new'
```

...but I keep getting this error

```
@request must be an ActionDispatch::Request
```

Am I doing this right? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
current_path.should == new_project_path
page.should have_selector('div#error_explanation')
```

According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105371/724036